# Semantics of x,¨y in APL: ie, what does it mean to map a catenate in APL?

Tags: arrays, map-function, apl, dyalog

Consider the expression `(1 2 3),¨(4 5 6)`. I expected this to "map the operation `(1 2 3),` on each of `4`, `5`, and `6`, giving the answer as:

```
(1 2 3),¨(4 5 6)
= (1 2 3),¨((4) (5) (6)) [Using (x) = x]
= (((1 2 3), 4) ((1 2 3), 5) ((1 2 3), 6)) [Using definition of map]
= ((1 2 3 4) (1 2 3 5) (1 2 3 6))
```

However,this is *not* the answer! The answer as evaluated in Dyalog APL is:

```
     ]display (1 2 3),¨(4 5 6) 
┌→──────────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │1 4│ │2 5│ │3 6│ │
│ └~──┘ └~──┘ └~──┘ │
└∊──────────────────┘
```

How? What's the reasoning behind this answer? Where did I go wrong in my equational reasoning? Are there more "gotchas" that my incorrect mental model of `, (comma)` and `¨(map)` that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`,` is a symmetric function, it simply concatenates its arguments.

`¨` is also symmetric, it pairs up elements from left and and right.

According to APL's [scalar extension](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Scalar_extension) rules, a single element as argument gets distributed to pair up with all the elements from the other argument.

You speak of *the operation `(1 2 3),`* but there is no such operation. If you try to give this "function" a name, it'll fail with a `SYNTAX ERROR`.

However, you *can* create a function which takes its argument and appends it to `1 2 3` as [Richard Park demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60565272/5306507); `1 2 3∘,` and you can then map that function over the elements of an array with `1 2 3∘,¨`.

Comment: Ah, the insight that `(1, 2, 3),` is not a function, but it's the `,` was the insight that I was missing. I was thinking in terms of haskell-style currying, which only comes into picture when `∘` exists. That's very enlightening, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
1 2 3,¨4 5 6
```

Catenate each element of `1 2 3` with each element of `4 5 6`

```
1 2 3∘,¨4 5 6
```

Catenate `1 2 3` with each element of `4 5 6`

```
      (2 2⍴⍳4),¨(2 2⍴⎕A)
┌───┬───┐
│1 A│2 B│
├───┼───┤
│3 C│4 D│
└───┴───┘
      (2 2⍴⍳4)∘,¨(2 2⍴⎕A)
┌─────┬─────┐
│1 2 A│1 2 B│
│3 4 A│3 4 B│
├─────┼─────┤
│1 2 C│1 2 D│
│3 4 C│3 4 D│
└─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: So just to be clear, `¨` when used dyadically behaves like `zipWith`?